# SVG circle animation stroke on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, css-animations

I currently have a small SVG that adds a full stroke. However, I am having hard time for a full circle to be completed on **hover**. When the user hovers off the link, it should go back the other way.

The full animation seems to be working but when integrating it, the animation keeps disappearing when I only want it to happen.

```css
body,
html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #D81D3B;
}
.svg-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
.svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.symbol {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-dasharray: 1600;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1600;
  animation: dash 4s linear 1;
}
@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1600;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: -1600;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-container">
  <svg width="100" height="100" class="svg">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke-width="4" class="symbol" />
  </svg>

</div>

<a href="#">Stupid</a>
```

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding what the default state vs the hover state should be. Please clarify the exact behavior you're attempting.

Comment: @SophieRhodes: I've added a couple of tags that maybe helpful for future searches. If you feel that they are not correct, please feel free to roll back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description what you actually need is a `transition` and not an `animation`. Also, the link (`a`) element is currently below the `svg` element in DOM and so it can't be used to alter the styles of the SVG element (or the SVG's children). It needs to be above the SVG element (above means that the link should be a previous sibling of the SVG element or a previous sibling of the SVG's parent).

Another thing is you don't actually need to move from `stroke-dashoffset:1600` to `-1600` because it will paint the circle and immediately wipe it off. We need it to be `stroke-dashoffset:0` when hovering on the link element and go back to original state (`stroke-dashoffset: 1600`) on hover out. Transitions will automatially create the reverse effect on hover out and there is no need for separate coding.

Below is a sample snippet.

```css
body,
html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #D81D3B;
}
.svg-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
.svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.symbol {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-dasharray: 1600;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1600;
  transition: all 4s linear;
}
a:hover + .svg-container .symbol {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Stupid</a>
<div class="svg-container">
  <svg width="100" height="100" class="svg">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke-width="4" class="symbol" />
  </svg>

</div>
```

---

Making the circle wipe out in the same direction (clockwise) on hover out isn't possible with transitions or plain CSS. It can be achieved with some JS like in the below snippet. When using JS, link element can be anywhere in the document as it doesn't have restrictions like CSS and using animations will be more effective than transitions.

(*Note: Very quick hover in and out will break the animation because the script expects one iteration to be completed by the time a hover out happens. Fixing this would be very tricky and complex.*)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var link = document.querySelector('a');
  var symbol = document.querySelector('.svg-container .symbol');

  /* clockwise paint on hover in */
  link.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    symbol.setAttribute('style', 'stroke-dashoffset: 1600; animation: paint 4s linear');
  }, false);

  /* clockwise wipe on hover out */
  link.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    symbol.setAttribute('style', 'stroke-dashoffset: 0; animation: wipe 4s linear');
  }, false);
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #D81D3B;
}
.svg-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
.svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.symbol {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-dasharray: 1600;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1600;
}
@keyframes paint {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes wipe {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: -1600;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-container">
  <svg width="100" height="100" class="svg">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke-width="4" class="symbol" />
  </svg>
</div>
<a href="#">Stupid</a>
```

Comment: thanks for coming back. On the hover over effect, it works perfectly but on hover off, it would need to go the other side like it does in my current animation. Would that possible?

Comment: @SophieRhodes: Oh I see. But that wouldn't be possible with transitions or CSS. It is not very easy also and would need some scripting (JS). Because we are saying default state is offset 1600, on hover it goes to 0 and then on hover out it goes to -1600. I will add a JS sample if you want.

Comment: that would be great learning. I presume you are toggling classes? with the offset moving back and forth -1600 and 1600

Comment: @SophieRhodes: I've added a JS version also. I'm toggling animations on hover in/out to get the effect. I am not a JS expert so my script can be optimized.